# How would you know if there was an AD issued for an aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, regulations, new-airplane

How would I know if an AD was issued?

Is this information only given to owners of the aircraft? Or must you sign up with the FAA or Manufacturing company to get emails about that sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [FAA Site](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/airworthiness_directives) allows you to sign up for email delivery of new AD's.